# Fancybox add link to popup image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I have a popup on page load that displays a image, when clicking somewhere it closes. I want the popup to be a link that goes to another page. Any ideas?

My current code:

HTML:

```
<a id="hidden_link" href="image.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;"><img src="image.jpg")</a>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {                        
$("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

This Jquery triggers a hidden link so the fancybox shows. Is there a way to add a link to the image.jpg?

using fancybox 1.3.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, if you are hiding the element (`visibility:hidden`),  you don't need to use a thumbnail (`<img>`) in your html code, otherwise you are just adding an extra overhead to your page load so this should be enough :

```
<a id="hidden_link" href="image.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

Second, to add a link to the image already opened in fancybox, you can use the `.wrap()` method within fancybox's `onComplete` callback like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox({
        onComplete: function () {
            $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
                // set anchor attributes
                href: this.href, //or your target link
                target: "_blank" // optional
            }));
        }
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bVeD8/)</kbd>

**NOTE**: this is for fancybox v1.3.4

Answer (score 4):

Fancybox updated their plugin.
The way writted by @JFK works fine in older versions, but int the version 2.1.5 you need to change a simple method.

Inseatd use `onComplete`, you have to use `afterShow`.

Then, the final code is:

1) The hidden link

```
<a id="hidden_link" href="image.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

2) The JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox({
        afterShow: function () {
            $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a />", {
                // set anchor attributes
                href: this.href, //or your target link
                target: "_blank" // optional
            }));
        }
    }).trigger("click");
});
```

This work fine for me.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. You are targeting the wrong selector, which is not the same for v2

Comment: Correct selector: `$(".fancybox-image")`

Answer (score 1):

You can force the content (adding your link)
Check for the advanced option "content" in Fancybox API (http://fancybox.net/api)

Here it goes:

```
 $("#hidden_link").click(function () {
     $.fancybox.open({
         height: '100',
         padding: 5,
         content: '<P>Just a test</P>'
     });
 });
```

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: Hi, thanks. i See that option. Could you tell me how i should write that in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jQuery :

`var popup_link = '<a id='popup_link' href='www.example.com/example'></a>';`

`$('.fancybox-inner').html(popup_link);`

Css :

`#popup_link { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;}`